# c++/cli Посоветуйте с include'ами

Tags: c++, c++-cli, include

Есть понимание что у меня проблемы с инклудами. В данный момент есть программа с 4мя формами и кучей классов.
Все классы я перечислил в отдельном .h файле и в формах ссылаюсь на него
    #include "includes.h"
Проблема в том что со временем в программе накапливались классы и формы и includes.h рос.
Классы стали пересекаться, один использует другой а в другом вызывается третий.
Программа работает, но пришлось вставлять #include "includes.h" уже в .h файл каждой формы, потому что в какой то момент .h файл форм перестал видеть данный инклуд в .cpp файле формы. В результате классы компилируются по 10 раз для каждого инклуда, и в результате компиляция занимает достаточно много времени.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне прописать все инклуды правильно?

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне прописать все инклуды правильно?

Перво-наперво, как указали в удаленном сообщении - нужно использовать [`include-guard`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) - методику, желательно в виде [`#pragma once`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once). Это более современный способ. И это даст возможность однократного включения заголовков.

Второй момент - разбор с "бизнес-логикой". Когда классы работают "все-со-всеми", это заведомо глючный салат. Нужно определится "кто с кем взаимодействует". Если есть перекрестные взаимодействия - используйте упреждающие объявления. В принципе, одно из решений - упреждающие объявления и выносить их нужно отдельно, пусть в `global_include.h`. Например:

```
#pragma once

class ClassDrinkVodka;
class ClassRunToMaidan;
class ClassJumpForPeremoga;
class ClassZradaCry;
```

Тут последовательность взаимодействия заранее не определена. И именно этот файл можно включать глобально. А заголовки-реализации - по необходимости. Системы сборки уже сами будут смотреть за ситуацией, что изменено и что требуется перекопилировать.

Но лучше всего на один класс - одну пару (`*.h` и `*.cpp`) файлов. Несколько классов в файле оправдано только в том случае, если решается крайне локальный функционал.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и

```
#pragma once
```

а можно обернуть весь .h файл в

```
#ifndef INCLUDES_H
#define INCLUDES_H

// все содержимое

#endif // INCLUDES_H
```

Второй вариант в данном случае так же хорош, а в целом - лучше, так как намного более распространен.

И все-таки действительно лучше определиться, кому какой класс нужен, и соответственно указывать includ'ы